# Using \let to change the argument of a a \newif command

Tags: conditionals

I want to be able to switch mid-document between writing indices as subscripts vs within parens, e.g., `x_t vs x(t)`.  I've written some code to do this, see below.    Everything is conditioned on the setting of \subParen, which selects one or other branch of a `\newif` macro called `\ifstrcmp`.  If I write `\def\subParen{sub}` I get subscripts, and `\def\subParen{parens}` I get parentheses.   I'd like to be able to swich back and forth within the document using, `\let\subParen\parens`  and `\let\subParen\sub`.     However, `\let` doesn't do what it normally does in this case.     The example below illustrates.    In the example, I succesfully use a `\let` call to change a secondary variable called `\whichIndex` but I really need to change the variable `\subParen` for all to work properly.

I'd really appreciate some advice on how to get the `\let\subParen\parens` command to work, thanks

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}%duplicating so that \isstrcmp below will work
\makeatother
\newif\ifstrcmp
\makeatletter
\def\isstrcmp#1#2{
        \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=0
                \strcmptrue
        \else
                \strcmpfalse
        \fi
}
\makeatother
%The setting on \subParen should determine whether to use subscripts or parens
\def\subParen{sub}
\isstrcmp{\subParen}{sub}
\ifstrcmp
    \def\whichIndex{\subIndex}
\else
    \def\whichIndex{\parenIndex}
\fi
\def\subIndex#1{_{{#1}}}
\def\parenIndex#1{({#1})}
%e.g., \toppedVar{x}{\hat}{t} is 
%       \hat{x}_{t} if \whichToppedIndex is set to \toppedSubIndex
%       \hat{x}(t)  if \whichToppedIndex is set to \toppedParenIndex
\def\toppedVar#1#2#3{#2{#1}\whichIndex{#3}}
%e.g., \besideVar{x}{\ast}{t} is 
%       {x}_{t}^\ast if \whichBesideIndex is set to \besideSubIndex
%       {x}(t)^\ast  if \whichBesideIndex is set to \besideParenIndex
\def\besideVar#1#2#3{
    \ifstrcmp
        #1\whichIndex{#3}^{#2}
    \else
        #1^{#2}\whichIndex{#3}
    \fi
}

\def\xStar#1{\besideVar{x}{\ast}{#1}}
\def\xHat#1{\toppedVar{x}{\hat}{#1}}
\begin{document}
Should be subscripts: $\xStar{t} \xHat{t}$\\

\let\subParen\nothing
Should be parens: $\xStar{t} \xHat{t}$\\

\let\whichIndex\parenIndex
Should be parens with asterisk before parens: $\xStar{t} \xHat{t}$\\
\end{document}
```

~

Comment: The `\def\whichIndex` are not re-executed by modifying `\subParen` after the fact. You would need to re-execute `\isstrcmp` to set up your conditionals to be used in `\besideVar`.

Comment: You mean \let\whichIndex=\subIndex and \let\whichIndex=\parenIndex?  (Actually, the = is optional, but I like to include them for clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jfbu's comment, I added the following \def statements to my preamble.

```
\def\useParens{\isstrcmp{\subParen}{parens} \ifstrcmp \def\whichIndex{\subIndex} \else \def\whichIndex{\parenIndex}\fi}
\def\useSubs{\isstrcmp{\subParen}{sub} \ifstrcmp \def\whichIndex{\subIndex} \else \def\whichIndex{\parenIndex} \fi}
```

Now, if I type `\useParens` or `\useSubs` in the body of the text, \xStar{t} will return, respectively, `x^ast(t)` or `x_t^\ast` which is exactly what I wanted.    Thanks again, @jfbu.